# 3D Printing Plot3D

Tags: graphics

I would like to prepare 3D plots for printing in a 3D printer. The printer does not print lines or surfaces because they have zero thickness. So I have to replace them with `Cylinder`s. Is there  way to make Mathematica use `Cylinder` (and `Sphere`s at each intersection) in presenting the mesh? Perhaps by specifying `MeshFunctions->f[Cylinder[],Sphere[]]`? I thought I'd start with `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> (Sphere[{#1, #2, #3}, .05]) &]` but that went over like a lead balloon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{style, Tube[radius]}` as a styling directive to set `MeshStyle`:

```
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 90,
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[], 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> 10, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Red, Tube[.05]}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Blue, Tube[.05]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and economical! Many thanks.

Comment: @NicholasG, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 4):

*Update:*

This will create a mesh or net, without the surface, which is more in line with the OP's desires (see comment below):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None]] /.
 Line[p_] :> {Sphere[p, .03], Tube[p, 0.03]}
```

---

*Original answer:*

I can't test 3D printing, but maybe [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) could be used to replace `Line`:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}] /. Line[p_] :> Tube[p, 0.02]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adjust the radius `0.02` to suit printing needs, assuming `Tube` is rendered properly.

One can use [`Cylinder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cylinder.html) like this:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}] /. 
 Line[p_] :> (Cylinder[#, 0.02] & /@ Partition[p, 2, 1])
```

The ends of adjacent cylinders won't match exactly as can be seen below. I don't know if that would need fixing before printing.  (This does not happen with `Tube`.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. Replace your code with `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None]] /. Line[p_] :> {Sphere[p, .03], Tube[p, 0.03]}` so as to take care of the joints by putting `Spere`s at the joints and I'll accept it!

Comment: @NicholasG Done. BTW, are there problems with the joints using `Tube`? I can see it happening with `Cylinder`, but I didn't expect it with `Tube`.

Comment: @NicholasG That close-up is of the cylinders.  With `Tube`, I see no wedges: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HZuzf.png

Comment: I thought that the problem would wedge-form gaps produced on the oblique side of angles and putting spheres in there would cure the problem. I thought there were such gaps in the intersection that is in the foreground in your close-up. But it turns out I was wrong, the tubes do not leave gaps in bends. But the spheres might still help at the ends.